# Moving a divsquare in another div (infinite loop)

Tags: javascript

how do I get a button to move a square in the container as long as I click on the button?
(from up left to down left, to down right, to up right, then to up left, indefinitely)

I tried to make a switch case but I kinda forget the logic I can put to get this work.
If I don't specify any conditions and give only one instruction to the button, it works

```
   move.onclick = function deplacement() {
        img.style.top = (img.offsetTop + 100) + "px";
        }
```

But this code doesn't

```js
//I am not sure if I should define the meaning of the position:   

let positionUpLeft = img.offsetLeft == 0 px && img.offsetTop == 0 px;
let positionBotLeft = img.offsetLeft == 0 px && img.offsetTop == 100 px;
let positionBotRight = img.offsetLeft == 100 px && img.offsetTop == 100 px;
let positionUpRight = img.offsetLeft == 100 px && img.offsetTop == 100 px;


if (positionUpLeft) {
  move.onclick = function deplacement() {
    img.style.top = (img.offsetTop + 100) + "px";
    positionBotLeft;
  }
} else if (positionBotLeft) {
  move.onclick = function deplacement() {
    img.style.left = (img.offsetLeft + 100) + "px";
    positionBotRight;
  }
} else if (positionBotRight) {
  move.onclick = function deplacement() {
    img.style.top = (img.offsetTop - 100) + "px";
    positionUpRight;
  }
} else if (positionHauteDroite) {
  move.onclick = function deplacement() {
    img.style.left = (img.offsetLeft - 100) + "px";
    positionUpLeft;
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

#img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="img"></div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <p><button id="move" type="submit" name="move">move</button></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example from W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_controllers_moving

Check also Html5 drag and drop: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp